# Stop page from scrolling on android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I have been attempting to stop my web page from scrolling, this works easy enough on desktop browsers with overflow: hidden; but this will not work on my android tab, it just seems to keep scrolling no matter what i do. I have played around with preventDefault on scroll but this doesn't seem to work at all.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```